# How to use ReactJS components defined in one .js file in a html file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, reactjs-native

I have defined my reactjs components in my HTML file like the following:

```
<script type="text/babel">
 var WorkHistory = React.createClass({
......
});
                  ReactDOM.render(
                        <WorkHistory 
                        />,
                        document.getElementById('work_history')
                    );
</script>
```

Now, I can easily use this in my HTML page. But, I need to write the entire entire code like this:

**WORKHISTORY.js file:**

```
var WorkHistory = React.createClass({
    ......
    });
```

**WORKHISTORY.html file:**

```
<script type="text/babel">
                      ReactDOM.render(
                            <WorkHistory 
                            />,
                            document.getElementById('work_history')
                        );
</script>
```

How can I achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to write your components in separate `.js`-files and be able to access them in the `<script>`-tag where you use `ReactDOM.render`?

If that is the case, simply include `<script>`-tags with the `src`-attribute set to the path of your files *before* the rendering tag, as per my example:

```
<script src="./path/to/workhistory.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
  ReactDOM.render(
    <WorkHistory />,
    document.getElementById('work_history')
  );
</script>
```

Comment: In that case I get an error :

'ReferenceError: WorkHistory is not defined'

Comment: Oh, well I see now that you're using Babel to transpile your code. Babel will transform your code and prepend `'use strict'`, which encapsulates the scope of that file, preventing your other `script`-tags from accessing its variables.


If you're just testing stuff out, you can use the global scope - `window` - when assigning and accessing your variables, but a better solution would be to use [a build system](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/) with Babel instead.